# Issue in deploying data to Streamlit via Github from Snowflake

Tags: github, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I have created a table and inserted value in Snowflake database, now I want to run through GitHub and display on Streamlit web page but its throwing me the error. as shown in picture.

On Streamlit under secret setting option I have added below command, password and username are not shown for safety reasons.  When I save the code in GitHub and check on Streamlit it throws error.

Need help as I am badly stuck.

```
[snowflake] user = "*" ,password = "*", account = "*" , warehouse = " pc_rivery_wh" ,database = "pc_rivery_db"  ,schema = "public",role = "accountadmin"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. What’s the error message?